# Why title property is not displaying?

Tags: json, vue.js

```
<script setup> 
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const products = ref([])

async function  fetch() {
try {
const response = await axios.get('http://dummyjson.com/products?limit=10');
return response.data


catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
     }
    }


onMounted(async () => {
const fetchedProducts = await fetch()
console.log(fetchedProducts)
products.value = fetchedProducts
console.log(products.value)
 });

 </script>

 <template>
    <nav>
       <div class="nav">

      </div>
   </nav>
  <div class="productContaier">
      <p v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">{{ product.title }}</p>
  </div>

  </template>
```

When i try to display just product it displays entire json but when i try to display product.title it does nothing. Why?

When i tried it with other data (json that i created in my computer) it worked. Why it doesnt work with dummyjson?  Also in console data are correct and succesfully loaded.

Comment: It's unknown what "other data" was. Likely because your expectations are wrong. fetchedProducts is an object with products key, not an array

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script setup>

import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";

const data = ref(null);

function get() {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "https://dummyjson.com/products",
        params: {
            limit: 10,
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        data.value = response.data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

onMounted(() => {
    get();
});

</script>
<template>
    <div v-if="data">
        <p v-for="product in data.products" :key="product.id">
            {{ product.title }}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

successfully tested here